# xPath: select following-sibling and self nodes

Tags: xpath, siblings

From this piece of HTML:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
    <tr id="1" class="first">
    <tr id="2" class="">
    <tr id="3" class="last">
    <tr id="4" class="first">
    <tr id="5" class="">
    <tr id="6" class="last">
<tbody>
```

I´m trying to get an xPath expression to return all tr[@class='first'] nodes followed by tr which don´t have a "first" class, including the first node. In this case a set with tr ids 1, 2, 3 and tr with ids 4, 5, 6.

I´ve tried using:

```
//tbody/tr[@class='first']/self::* | following-sibling::tr[not(starts-with(@class, 'first'))]
```

With no success. Any thoughts on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not *exactly* what you want, this expression will return all nodes between a first and last class, but it won't group them together. That's the best you'll be able to do with just one XPath expression.

Given an input like this,

```
<tbody>
  <tr id="0" class=""/>
  <tr id="1" class="first"/>
  <tr id="2" class=""/>
  <tr id="3" class="last"/>
  <tr id="4" class="first"/>
  <tr id="5" class=""/>
  <tr id="6" class="last"/>
  <tr id="7" class=""/>
</tbody>
```

This XPath expression,

```
/tbody/tr[
  (following-sibling::tr[@class='last'] and preceding-sibling::tr[@class='first'])
  or @class='first' or @class='last'
]
```

Will return these nodes:

```
<tr id="1" class="first" />
<tr id="2" class="" />
<tr id="3" class="last" />
<tr id="4" class="first" />
<tr id="5" class="" />
<tr id="6" class="last" />
```

The expression works by checking all `tr` elements whose preceding sibling is a 'first' and whose following sibling is a 'last'. That way it will exclude `tr`s outside of those.

However, it does not do any grouping. I do not know of any way to do that kind of grouping with a single XPath expression. If I had to do it, I would have one XPath expression return all 'first' `tr`s, then march through its siblings until I find 'last' `tr`. Maybe someone else knows of a better way to do this.

Comment: Thanks, I´ll give it a go using position() and some PHP instead